# How does the first post review queue work on this site?

Tags: support, reviewing

Today I came across some low quality posts, answering [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42822/i-have-no-cousins-in-antarctica-who-am-i) question.

[image]

The members seem to be users since today. Why did their posts not land in the First Posts review queue, as on other (say SO) SE sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Because AJ and I were too quick for you.

The answers you refer to *did* show up in the First Posts review queue, but by the time you reached the review queues they'd already been reviewed there and flagged to send them into the Low Quality Posts review queue:

- https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/24412

  [image: screenshot]
- https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/24413

  [image: screenshot]
- https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/24417

  [image: screenshot]

Comment: So even though some posts were reviewed by two regulars, and flagged as "low quality", they do indeed showed up on the site (as expected)? I am afraid I don't quite see the whole point of reviewing in the first place. Do I understand correctly that now the posts landed in the LQPRQ, which is another queue, cleared by moderators?

Comment: Oh I kind of see now. Just I got confused because the meta-review page and the main-review pages are different. So you vote to delete there, but that takes a few people's vote, and maybe there are not so many people around... This kind of clears things up. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Matsmath In the First Posts review queue, each new user's first post gets reviewed by one 500+ rep user. Any post which is flagged as "very low quality" or "not an answer", or which is sufficiently short to be auto-flagged by the system, goes into the Low Quality Posts review queue to be reviewed by 2000+ rep users; enough delete votes from them will cause the post to be deleted.